# Is the sum of two irrational numbers irrational, if the two are not additive inverses?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Tried assuming the existence of two irrationals whose sum is rational, then looking for a contradiction, but haven't made progress yet.

Any hints/counterexamples would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $(x+y)-x=0$, for all real numbers $x$ and all rational numbers $y$. If $x$ is irrational, what can you tell about $x+y$?

Comment: No, $3+\sqrt{2}$ and $3-\sqrt{2}$ are irrational and the sum is $6$, so they are not additive inverses

Comment: Great, thank you guys! I see it now

Comment: y = irrational and x = 27 - y.  So x + y =27 ! = 0.  So ... no.  But we can say x + y is irrational if y != q - x for some rational q... but then we think about it and realize ... that's inane and trivial.  x + y = q iff y = q - x so... not really much more we can say.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are irrational, but $r = x+y$ is rational, then $x+y = x+(r-x)$, so any concrete example will look as trivial as the ones above (e.g. $(3+\sqrt2) + (6- (3+\sqrt2))$ in Peter's example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x, y$ are irrational.  Then $x + y = q \in \mathbb Q \iff y = q - x$.

And that's ... pretty much all we can say.  $x$ and $q-x$ are not additive inverses if $q \ne 0$.

I get what you are asking.  You want to know if you can have two utterly "unrelated" irrational numbers adding up to a rational?  Probably not, it seems.  But then we have to define what "unrelated" means.  And it probably means something like "we can't get $y$ from $x$ by doing simple arithmetic with just $x$ and rational numbers".  But then if we want $x + y \in \mathbb Q$ that *means* $y = q-x$ for some rational $q$. So by *definition* $x + y \in \mathbb Q$ *mean*s $x$ and $y$ are "related". So the "no" answer is utterly trivial.